# the direction of >= sign when an equation is subjected to a condition

Tags: simple-functions

> We have 2 equations
>
> $$\frac{A}{I} = 2Tw$$
>
> and
>
> $$\frac{K+Z}{I} = w^2$$
>
> and a condition that needs to be satisfied to find $A$:
>
> where
>
> $$T\geq 1$$

Does that mean $\frac{A}{I} \geq 2w$ or $\frac{A}{I} \leq 2w$

I am trying to solve for $A$ with respect to the other variables $K$ and $Z$ and $I$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $ A/I=2wT $ and $T\ge1 $ then $A/I\ge 2w$.  Why did you tag this [tag:ordinary-differential-equations]?

Comment: thanks, that cleared things up for me

Comment: I was assuming $w\ge0$; is that valid?